# Horizontal list li not taking up the whole height

Tags: html, css

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-home"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Elements</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
</ul>

.nav {
  line-height: 70px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
.nav li {
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
}
.active {
  background: pink;
}
.icon-home {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNme0.png) no-repeat;
  width: 16px;
  height: 14px;
  display:block;
}
body {
  background: gray;
}
```

How do I make the background of `.active` take up the whole height of `li` and center the icon? If you check the demo it doesn't respect the line-height of the `li`.

Demo: <strike>http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ulEGw</strike>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set `.icon-home` to `display: inline-block;`, which will center it vertically with the rest of the text.

You can also keep your `line-height` this way.

Comment: @Hermione You have an extra style rule there, .nav a {display: block;}, which is causing it to look different.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to keep your `line-height: 70px` on `.nav`, put `height: 70px;` on `.icon-home`.